# Maximum file upload size in SharePoint 2010

Tags: file-upload

What is the **maximum upload file size** accepted by SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is actually 2GB in SP2010 and SP2007, and this is a hard limit. However, each web application by default is set to 50MB. You can go to the General Settings of a Web Application and tweak this setting.

Answer (score 4):

Each Web Application By default have 50MB for one time attachment to be uploaded. You can modify it from:

**Central Admin -> Manage Application -> Select your web application -> General Setting -> Set Max Upload Size**

If file size is too large then you should also update `executionTimeOut` (Increase this time from IIS Setting) value and `ConnectionTimeou`t (Update this time from web application web.config file) value.

Answer (score 1):

As in 2007 you can specify it.
This article in technet is a quite good read, it talks about digital asset management on SharePoint 2010 and how you should plan things ahead:

[Digital asset library topology and architecture (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721060%28office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Great, also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428298%28office.14%29.aspx contains a couple of other links.