# Uploading large files to SP 2010 - InfoPath limits and alternatives

Tags: 2010, infopath, file-upload, attachments

*Problem*)

We have several complex InfoPath forms in production. Got a new requirement for one of them: Client needs to be able to **upload large files** to SP libraries **using this IP form** (as file attachments).

*Caveat*)

Although it is technically possible (incrementing user session data -to allow large files- and moving programmatically the attachment to a SP library -to don't blow up the form-), it seems like [it is not recommended because of the performance impact on the farm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jorman/performance-impact-of-file-attachments-in-infopath-forms).

*Looking for solutions*)

Thus, we are thinking about how can we manage this situation (leveraging the already designed InfoPath form). We have thought about **several alternatives**:

**1)** "Embedding" a FileUpload ASP.NET control within the form.

**2)** Simply put a link pointing to an ASP.NET page containing the FileUpload control.

*Problems with the solutions*)

1. I think it's not technically possible to upload files from InfoPath without using the user/form session storage (even if it were possible to embed the FileUpload control within the form).
2. Since we want to know if the user has uploaded a file -and, in that case, which file it was- (to insert the proper reference inside the form), we would need some kind of "feedback" coming back from the ASP.NET page to the form. [It would be like a synchronous call, waiting for the task to be done ... and then informing about the results of it].

Anyone can give me his/her two cents? I have been reading/thinking for a while ... and wasn't able to come with a feasible solution (I mean, any other than reimplementing the whole form from scratch without using InfoPath technology).

**Thank you** very much in advance!!

Comment: Don't want to change your requirement? If to upload files to sharepoint library then it [also has hard limit (2 GB) and by default 50 MB which can be changed from Sharepoint side](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/814/maximum-file-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2010) The problem is that Sharepoint stores them in content MSSQL database under the hood. I do not beleive that it is good to store big files in either Sharepoint or in database which you cannot directly configure

Comment: The problem exposed here is not to store that documents in a SP library (I agree it's not a good idea, though). Question is about workarounds in order to upload files from an InfoPath form without using the user/form session temporal storage. Anyway thanks for your comment Gennady Vanin! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not the answer but also a little heavy for a comment...

Don't want to change your requirement?
If to upload files to sharepoint library then it [also has hard limit (2 GB) and by default 50 MB which can be changed from Sharepoint side](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/814/maximum-file-upload-size-in-sharepoint-2010) The problem is that Sharepoint stores them in content MSSQL database under the hood. I do not beleive that it is good to store big files in either Sharepoint or in database which you cannot directly configure

I would have stored big files in the file system... Here is an article about:

- [SharePoint 2010: Storing Documents on the File System with Remote Blob Storage](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/sharepoint-2010-storing-documents-on-the-file-system-with-remote-blob-storage/)

**Update:**

There are multiple locations where it should be adjusted:

- [Infopath Forms Services and webapplication through Sharepoint Central Administration](http://sams177.blogspot.ru/2012/04/how-to-increase-file-upload-size-in.html)
- [maxRequestlength in the Machine.config file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330809) on local computers
- maxRequestLength in SharePoint Web.Config

and I am not sure that they eventualy help

I would have asked this in Microsoft forum:

- [SharePoint 2010 - Using SharePoint Designer, InfoPath and Other Customizations](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/threads)

where the questions are being answered by Microsoft workers. IMO, they are trying to answer each question there and when they cannot, then forward it to more qualified experts until finding an eventual answer, be it lucky or not

Comment: The problem exposed here is not about the final location where documents are stored (although I agree it could be problematic to keep large files inside the DB). Question's goal is to find any workaround able to upload files from an InfoPath form without using the user/form session temporal storage. Anyway thanks for your time man! ;)

Comment: I updated my answer